# Solve equation with logarithm base 10

Tags: logarithms

I am going back to study log and unfortunately I don't know a lot.
I need to solve this:
$$
    100= 10\log_{10} \left(50/x\right)
$$
I did the wrong calculation just moving stuff to the left, but I've been told is not right:
$$\begin{align}
    100 \cdot x &= 10\log_{10} \cdot 50\\
    x &= \left(10\log_{10} \cdot 50\right) / 100\\
    x &= 0.016
\end{align}$$
I know that it is wrong, can someone explain me how to solve this?

Comment: Could you use brackets in your formulas? It's not clear if you mean $^{10}\log(10)\cdot\frac{50}x$, $^{10}\log\left(10\cdot\frac{50}x\right)$ or $10\log_{10}\left(\frac{50}x\right)$. I suppose it's the third one.

Comment: yes it's the third one barto, thanks a lot, sorry I am learning to use the site

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$x\ne 0$ is part of the argument of $\log_{10},\,$ you cannot move it out the way you did. You can use $\log_{10}(50/x)= \log_{10}50 -\log_{10}x,\,$ or something like this:
$$100 = 10\log_{10}\left(\frac{50}{x}\right)\quad (x\ne0)$$
$$\iff 10 = \log_{10}\left(\frac{50}{x}\right)$$
$$\iff 10^{10}=\frac{50}{x}$$
$$\iff x=\frac{50}{10^{10}}=\frac{1}{200000000}=5\times10^{-9}$$

Answer (score 2):

The mistake is that we can't just pull the factor $\frac1x$ out of the logarithm, i.e, $$\log_{10}\left(\frac{50}x\right)\neq\log_{10}(50)\cdot\frac1x$$ in general. The logarithm (in particular the base-$10$ logarithm) has no rule like
$$\log(a\cdot b)=\log(a)\cdot\log(b).$$
(In fact we have $\log ab=\log a+\log b$.)

What we can use here is:
$$\log_{10}(a)=b\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad a=10^b.$$

Before making this possible, we need a small manipulation to the given equation:
$$100=10\cdot\log_{10}\left(\frac{50}x\right)\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad10=\log_{10}\left(\frac{50}x\right).$$
Now we can apply the above rule, with $a=\frac{50}x$ and $b=10$:
$$\frac{50}x=a=10^b=10^{10}.$$
Look, the logarithm has disappeared! From here we can conclude
$$x=\frac{50}{10^{10}}=\frac1{200000000}.$$